# how to get original image size when file opening and calling imageareaselect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling with calling ImageAreaSelect per their website example and getting the original image size parameters for proper scaling of the crop selections.  The available cropping area is the full width of the container (I'd rather it be the image width), and I've used a max-width parameter in css to limit loaded file widths to less than the container.  There are lots of examples of rescaling the selectors, but how do I get the original width and height?  I am saving opened file name successfully for later js pixel manipulation on a separate canvas, but if an oversized image is loaded, then the selection results must be rescaled.

HTML:

```
<div class="container demo">
    <div style="float: left; width: 50%;">       
        <div class="frame" style="margin: 0 0.3em; width: 800px; height: 800px;">   
            <input type="file" id="file"/>
            <br />
            <div id="view"> Your image will load here</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imgContainer img { max-width: 600px;}
```

js:

```
function preview(img, selection) {
    if (!selection.width || !selection.height)
        return;

    // or do some conditional scaling here if image is large
    x_1 = selection.x1;   //I use these globals elsewhere for pixel calcs
    y_1 = selection.y1;
    S_wid = selection.width;
    S_hei = selection.height;
    L = Math.floor((S_wid * S_hei) / 4096);   //4-bit ave color density
}

$(function () {
    $('#view').imgAreaSelect({
        handles: true,
        fadeSpeed: 200,
        // imageHeight: originalHeight, //how to get these, or do elsewhere?
        // imageWidth: originalWidth,
        onSelectChange: preview
    });
});

$(window).load(function () {
    $('#file').change(function () {
        var oFReader = new FileReader();
        oFReader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        console.log(this.files[0]);
        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
            $('#view').html('<img src="' + oFREvent.target.result + '">');
            fname = oFREvent.target.result;  //global, used later elsewhere
            // some way to get original image sizes here, or do elsewhere?
        };
    });
});
```

I've been trying lots of suggested solutions, but have not been able to get anything to work properly.  `.width()` calls in the js functions just return the container width.  `.naturalWidth` calls following `getElementById` are undefined, unless I have a well defined img ID with `src="some file"`.  I don't know how to get or define an img ID for a file that's been opened this way in jquery.  Hopefully, there's something simple that I'm missing here.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `naturalWidth` isn't working because it's too soon to get that info from the image. You could try waiting until the image is loaded and then update imgAreaSelect (I checked their documentation, they have a method for setting options), e.g.

The following block of code would change from:

```
        $('#view').html('<img src="' + oFREvent.target.result + '">');
        fname = oFREvent.target.result;  //global, used later elsewhere
        // some way to get original image sizes here, or do elsewhere?
```

To something like:

```
        var $img = jQuery('<img src="' + oFREvent.target.result + '">')
        .on('load', function(){

            // The image's data will be available now, 
            // so update imgAreaSelect with the new values.
            var iAS = $('#view').imgAreaSelect({ instance: true });
            iAS.setOptions({
                handles: true,
                fadeSpeed: 200,
                imageHeight: this.naturalHeight,
                imageWidth: this.naturalWidth,
                onSelectChange: preview
            });            
        });
        $('#view').html($img);
        fname = oFREvent.target.result;  //global, used later elsewhere
```

I'm not sure how imgAreaSelect's `setOptions` method works, if we need to redeclare the original options or what, so you may not need to set `handles`, `fadeSpeed`, etc. over again.

Comment: This approach does provide the original height and width parameters that I was trying to access.  Thank you for the simple and direct code revision to access this info!